# If I go NG+, do I lose access to the Mapworks?

Tags: torchlight-2

The Mapworks is the only "town" in Torchlight 2 with:

- An enchanter that will enchant items thrice, Greezo
- Access to the map system
- [A wonderful music score](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Nf2y-JF7Rg)

Do I lose access to all of this if I go NG+?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I happened to just start NG+ (after safely backing up all my save files ofcourse), and you start out again in the 1st Act, in the 1st town (I forgot the name).

You can still travel to the Mapworks by using (any) Waypoint Portal.